# How to repeat a string with spaces?

Tags: python, string

I am trying string repetition in Python.

```
#!/bin/python
str = 'Hello There'
print str[:5]*2
```

**Output**

> HelloHello

**Required Output**

> Hello Hello

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Python version: 2.6.4

Comment: Does the required output have a trailing space after the second `Hello`?

Comment: @jozzas no mate.No trailing space after second hello.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
string = 'Hello There'
print ' '.join([string[:5]] * 2)
```

Comment: Mate justa  quick query , will this leave a trailing space after 2nd string?

Comment: No, it won't. It joins the two `Hello` strings with a space between them.

Comment: @misguided, it will not leave a trailing space after 2nd string.

Answer (score 20):

In case if you want just to repeat any string

```
"Hello world " * 2
```

Answer (score 10):

Do this:

```
str = 'Hello There'
print str[:6]*2
```

that will ad a space after the second "Hello" if that's ok. Also, like rajpy said you shouldn't use `str` as a variable because its a keyword in python.

Because then you're getting the space in between the two words and putting it in between the hello's

that should work!

P.S you don't need the `#!/bin/python`

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative solution, using string formatting with a repeated index:

```
print "{0} {0}".format(s[:5])   # prints "Hello Hello" if s is "Hello World"
```

This will work well if you know ahead of time exactly how you want to repeat your string. If you want the number of repetitions to variable at run time, using `str.join` as in nuront's answer is probably better.

An advantage to using string formatting is that you're not limited just to repetition, though you can do it easily enough. You can also do other decorating in and around the the string, if you want (and the copies don't need to be treated the same):

```
 print "[{0!r}] ({0:_^15})".format(s[:5])   # prints "['Hello'] (_____Hello_____)"
```

That prints the `repr` of a first copy of a string inside of square brackets, followed by a second copy in parentheses, centered and padded by underscores to be 15 characters wide.

Comment: Very interesting . Specially the second part :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print (str[:5] + ' ') * 2
```

If you want to specify trailing space explicitly.

In your example, you could do:

```
print str[:6] * 2
```

Please don't use built-in types(str, int etc..) as variables in your program, it shadows its actual meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip mate . Will keep that in mind. Also would your first solution leave space after printing Hello for the second time?

Comment: Ya, it would. Use neuront solution, its better one.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
str = 'Hello There'
m = re.match("(\w+\ )",str)
m.group(1) * 2
```