# Create "n" digit number using just 9s where "n" is variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, if user inputs 5, output: 99999

I know I can use a for loop to string concatenate, and then int the string, but this solutions seems ineffective.

Comment: Once you've converted the input to an integer, you can do `"9" * user_value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python repeat string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183259/python-repeat-string)

Comment: What values of `n` are you considering? It hardly matters for any reasonable value; pick the one you find most readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
>>> my_count = 5
>>> int('9'*my_count)
99999
```

Here, `'9'*my_count` will repeat '9' five (`my_count`) times in a string and then I am type-casting it to `int` to get an integer value.

*Note: If you want return value as integer, then go with [kaya3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65543909/2063361) as it'll give better performance. But if you want the return value as string (without type-casting it to int), only then you should go with this answer as it will be more performance efficient.*

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```py
>>> n = 6
>>> 10**n - 1
999999
```

---

Performance comparison with the alternative, `int("9" * n)`:

```py
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('10**n - 1', setup='n = 1000')
3.0823026559999107
>>> timeit('int("9" * n)', setup='n = 1000')
10.0500816629999 # > 3 times slower
>>> timeit('10**n - 1', setup='n = 100000', number=100)
0.5580871940001089
>>> timeit('int("9" * n)', setup='n = 100000', number=100)
7.984304671000245 # > 14 times slower
```

In fact `10**n - 1` is asymptotically more efficient because exponentiation is computed by a [square and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm which does O(log n) arithmetic operations, whereas converting the string `"9" * n` to an integer does O(n) arithmetic operations.

Of course, if you want the output to be a string instead of an `int`, then you can just do `"9" * n`, and this will be the fastest way.

Comment: this feels like the optimal solution to this post, usually math is faster than string processing

Comment: `"9"*n` is *far* faster than `10**n - 1` for large values of `n`. (By large, I mean on the order of 100)

Comment: @chepner That's because you aren't converting the string to `int`. The question implies that the OP was building a string and then converting it to int, so they want the result as an int. Comparing `10**n - 1` with `int('9'*n)`, I get that the latter is over 3 times slower when `n=1000`. The reason is presumably because converting a base-10 string to `int` requires a linear number of operations, whereas `**` requires a logarithmic number of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
n=input()

result=int(('9'*int(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
length = int(input("How long: "))
print(int('9'*length))
```

Simple and sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
inputValue = 5

number = "9"

print(int(number * inputValue))
```

You can leave out the int() If you want to print a string. But it is important the the inputValue is a integer and that the number is a string.

Answer (score 0):

if the 9's can be a string then the shortest, perhaps not most idiomatic way, would be:

```
print("9" * int(input("How many 9's")))
```

otherwise if they have to be ints then just type cast it like this:

```
print(int("9"*int(input("How many 9's"))))
```