# How to repeat a string multiple times with spaces?

Tags: python, repeat

I want to pass one string with n times to repeat it with spaces, my code look like:

```
def repeating(word, n):
  return word * n
```

I want the output look like:

```
hello hello hello
```

with spaces between each string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat a string with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183259/how-to-repeat-a-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 7):

Try using `str.join` as well:

```
def repeating(word, n):
    return ' '.join([word] * n)
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/join.html):

> Returns a string made from the elements of an iterable.

You can specify the separator of the elements in an iterable, like here I specified a space.

Also the reason I add brackets to `word` is because only that way it becomes a list, check the below examples:

```
>>> word = 'foo'
>>> word * 5
'foofoofoofoofoo'
>>> [word] * 5
['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']
>>> ' '.join(word * 5)
'f o o f o o f o o f o o f o o'
>>> ' '.join([word] * 5)
'foo foo foo foo foo'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want better performance, **don't use `join`**, instead, you can use formatted string and multiply it, then finally take the slice upto second last value (or `rstrip` will also work if the string itself doesn't end with space character):

```py
def repeat(word, n):
    return (f"{word} "*n)[:-1]

>>> repeat('hello', 10)
'hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello'
```

**Benchmark** for word = 'Hello' and n=100

using `join`:

```py
2.68 µs ± 300 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

without `join`:

```py
786 ns ± 62.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is some started code to try.  I declare an empty string and loop through to 'append' the word on the return string.

```
def repeating(word, n):
    returnString =""
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        returnString += word + " "
        i += 1
    return returnString

testString = repeating("hello", 3)
print(testString)
```

small note I dont think Im actually appending the string but rather a new string is being created each time the loop runs.

Comment: That's a pretty complicated and inefficient way to write `(word + " ") * n`. Plus it doesn't just add spaces "between" the strings but also one at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeating(word, n):
    return ((' ' + word) * n)[1:]
```

Benchmark with `word = 'hello'` and `n = 30000`:

```
0.49 ms  0.48 ms  0.49 ms  0.48 ms  0.49 ms  ' '.join([word] * n)
0.19 ms  0.19 ms  0.19 ms  0.19 ms  0.19 ms  ((' ' + word) * n)[1:]
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dasMwDIXv/RSHQLHdhrIuN6WlTxLC6JizetQ/KCpbnz6Vbdi5EdIn6Zz85FuKwzHTus6UAtgH5xk@5EQMctldWanF8SPjgu430ZdUfXP3e9JnRGmGN1Gn3F@mRdpRQdRp6P1P8tGM5WbCFtF2fWPGCMUOhdhKxsNpEjopNSfCB3wEXeO3M4M91ZsyLg6FVKc2LuLi2pKagnrUuD3iI3w6uhwknv3fzuQjm63Rm/37jLBIkA24/ufynBfbV4d20tbtur4A)):

```
from timeit import repeat

setup = "word = 'hello'; n = 30000"
exprs = [
    "' '.join([word] * n)",
    "((' ' + word) * n)[1:]",
]

for _ in range(3):
    for expr in exprs:
        ts = repeat(expr, setup, number=1000)
        print(*('%.2f ms ' % t for t in ts), expr)
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def repeating(word, n): 
    return word*(n>0) + (' ' + word)*(n-1)
```